# A faster way to compare lists for a common element in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a graph (implemented with Vector) of LinkedLists and I want to connect the LinkedLists that do not share any common elements. I think the way I do it right now takes O(n^3). I have a for loop that iterates through the Vector, then a nested for loop inside that iterates through the Vector (so that I can compare each List to every other one), then inside that for loop I use recursion to compare the Lists.

Before trying it this way, I tried having a while loop inside the 2nd for loop to iterate through each list and use a binary search to see if the 2nd list contains each element, but I think this takes the same amount of time or longer.
Here is my loop:

```
 public void addEdges(){
  for(int i =0; i < size()-1; i++){
   for(int j = i+1; j < size(); j++){
    if(compatible(get(i),get(j),1,1)){
     get(i).linkTo(get(j));
     get(j).linkTo(get(i));
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

and here is my recursion:

```
 public boolean compatible(Row a, Row b, int indexA, int indexB){
  if(a.get(indexA).getEnd() == b.get(indexB).getEnd()){
   return false;
  }
  else if(a.get(indexA).getEnd() == 0){
   return true;
  }
  else if(a.get(indexA).getEnd() > b.get(indexB).getEnd()){
   return compatible(a,b,indexA+1,indexB);
  }
  else{
   return compatible(b,a,indexB+1,indexA);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm reading this correctly, you can replace your `compatible` method with a call to the [`Collections.disjoint`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) static method.

Edit: Code sample:

```
public void addEdges(){
  for(int i =0; i < size()-1; i++){
   for(int j = i+1; j < size(); j++){
    if(Collections.disjoint(get(i),get(j))){
     get(i).linkTo(get(j));
     get(j).linkTo(get(i));
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Nice to make the code simpler, but his `compatible` method seems to be  relying on assumptions about the data structures, so it should be more efficient than the default method.

Comment: @Michael: I thought about that, but I figured I should post this either way, in case it really did do what he wanted.

Comment: @Michael: The confusion here is that I'm not really sure what `get(i)` and `get(j)` returned.  I assumed `LinkedList`, despite the `compatible` method taking a `Row` object.

Comment: I made a Row class that extends LinkedList. Sorry for the confusion. The rows are also sorted. Would the disjoint method be more efficient or would that also be O(n) (or even O(n^2))?

Comment: @SYL: Honestly, I'm not sure what the efficiency of this method is, as the JavaDoc just leaves it up to the implementation.  Having said that, if your `LinkedList` is sorted, you may be able to [`binarySearch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) it for faster results... I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

I might try a reverse index, `element -> [IDs of containing lists]`.  Iterating over the index will tell you which lists share elements, and thus can't be connected.

- Step 1: create reverse index
- Step 2: create incompatibility index, `list ID -> [IDs of incompatible lists]`
- Step 3: iterate over incompatiblity map to join lists which are compatible.

Step 3 may be more complicated if there are particular rules for joining compatible lists, since compatibility isn't transient.

---

Some pseudo-Java: For my own sake, I'm going to assume the data structures look like this (probably my `Bin` is your `Row`, more or less):

```
class Bin {
    ID id;
    LinkedList<Element> list;
}
```

The set of bins, `allBins` is of type `Collection<Bin>`.

Step 1:  The reverse index is of type `MultiValueMap<Element, ID>`.  That is, each element is mapped to a set of IDs (of bins containing that element).

```
MultiValueMap<Element, ID> reverseIndex;

for (Bin bin : allBins) {
    for (Element e : bin) {
        reverseIndex.put(e, bin.id);
    }
}
```

Step 2:  The incompatibility index is of type `MultiValueMap<ID, ID>`, where each bin ID is mapped to the set of bin IDs of incompatible bins.

```
MultiValueMap<ID, ID> incompatibilityIndex;

for (Element e : reverseIndex.keySet()) {
    List<ID> binsWithE = reverseIndex.get(e);
    for (ID id : binsWithE) {
        incompatibilityIndex.putAll(id, binsWithE); // each bin is incompat with itself
    }
}
```

Step 3:  Now we can join any two bins which aren't in each others incompatibility map.  Since joining two bins changes the incompatibilities, we have to be trickier:

```
Set<Bin> binsRemainingToProcess; // == original allBins
Set<Bin> binsProcessed; // == new allBins

while (binsRemainingToProcess.size() > 0) {
    Bin bin = // grab any bin to work on from binsRemainingToProcess

    // grab any compatible bins
    // could iterate until we find one, but I'm going to compute all compatible
    List<ID> compatibleBinIDs = // all bin IDs in binsRemaining...
    List<ID> incompatibleBinIDs = incompatibilityIndex.get(bin.id);
    compatibleBinIDs.removeAll(incompatibleBinIDs);

    if (compatibleBinIDs.size() > 0) {
        Bin otherBin = // some bin with ID in compatibleBinIDs

        // joining the two bins -- means joining the inner lists,
        // but also joining the incompatibilities
        joinDataStructures(bin, otherBin);
        incompatibilityIndex.putAll(bin.id, incompatibilityIndex.get(otherBinID));

        // we don't need the other bin anymore, but we may be able to join
        // the first bin to others
        binsRemainingToProcess.remove(otherBin);
    } else {
        // couldn't join with anyone; we're done with this bin and can move on
        binsRemainingToProcess.remove(bin);
        binsProcessed.add(bin);
    }
}
```

Okay, so that last one ended up being a lot more detailed than I planned...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Could you show me come example code or pseudocode? Is the reverse index a map with the elements as keys and lists of the containing lists as values, and the incompatibility index a map with the lists as keys and the lists of incompatible lists as values?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you are looking for faster way to do this and I think @Michael Brewer-Davis 
suggests a better way of doing this but is there a way to tackle the problem prior to creating
the lists ? So instead of comparing the lists when they are already created to make comparison when the lists are being created so you wouldn't have to recurse so brutally ? 
(what I mean is probably a design change: comparing the elements for inequality once only so that the unrelated elements a grouped together naturally and possibly avoiding recursion)

Comment: I don't think I can group them together in a way that would help me because each of the lists are unique.

Answer (score 0):

I actually thought of a faster way to compare my lists. I made a list of all the possible elements and now instead of lists of elements, I made an array of longs with each bit of the long representing whether or not they contain the corresponding element from the list of possible elements. Then I used the & operator to compare the longs to see if they have any common elements.